# spring boot admin showing only details tab

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-admin

[image]
[image]

I am not getting any other tabs like Environment,Loggers.Threads,Traces etc.. Except Details tab in Spring Boot Admin page.I have created the following micro services.
1)EurekaServer
2)ZuulGateway
3)Eurekaclient --2 instances

For all microservies only details tab is showing.

I am new to microservices.Any one please explain me and resolve my problem.Thank you.

admin-client properties:

```
#mongodb
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=Quickfix1

#logging
logging.level.org.springframework.data=debug
logging.level.=error

eureka.client.enabled=true
server.port=${PORT:0}
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8090/eureka
spring.application.name=EurekaClientOne

spring.boot.admin.client.enabled=true
spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:8099
spring.boot.admin.client.username=admin
spring.boot.admin.client.password=admin
logging.level.de.codecentric.boot.admin.client=DEBUG
```

Admin server properties:

```
spring.application.name=Boot-Admin
server.port=8099
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=admin
```

Comment: What are the properties you set in spring boot admin client?

Comment: @Anand spring.application.name=Boot-Admin
server.port=8099
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=admin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add below properties in your clients application property file/yml:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Please let me know if it works :)

Comment: have you set admin url?? ( spring.boot.admin.client.url ).
Please post your boot admin client and boot admin server property file details. Which spring boot and spring boot admin version are you using??

Comment: Please post your boot admin client and boot admin server property file details. Which spring boot and spring boot admin version are you using?? Its working perfectly on mine and without the specified property it shows only details tab.

Comment: Okay. Which version of spring boot admin and spring boot are you using?? There are slight changes in properties..

Comment: springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'

Comment: Please add the property which I have mentioned above and try again.

Comment: @After adding that property i am getting this exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either health or status endpoint must be enabled! –

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179034/discussion-between-anand-varkey-philips-and-nithin).

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue. On my spring boot application we had a cors filter to block Http Head requests. So head requests cannot be accepted.

- Check Javascript console log.
- Check your application filters which is blocking Http HEAD requests.
- Setting management.security.enabled=false in the application.properties also necessary.